# How to get intellisense/auto suggestion working for Plutus in VSCode?

Tags: plutus, cabal, vscode

I've been seeing Lars get auto suggestions from his terminal when he's typing. I want the same in VSCode, how to get it?

PS: I don't get auto suggestions in `cabal repl` too.

Answer (score 5):

Simply install the [Haskell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=haskell.haskell) from inside Visual Studio Code. You'll get there by pressing Ctrl+Shift+X and searching for Haskell.

Note that the extension requires a ghc installation (=<8.10.4) on your system. The current release of ghc 9.0.1 is not yet supported.